# fetching data from excel when cell contains null value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am fetching data from excel and I need to count rows where some cell contains null value. The code is returning nothing. For lines which contains some values in this cell it is working correctly. Can you help me how to handle cells with null value?

The code is following:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

        // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        // Iterate through rows
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Index of column D is 3 (A->0, B->1, etc)
            Cell cellD = row.getCell(3);
            Cell cellG = row.getCell(6);

            //
            String key = null;
            Integer value = null;

            // finding cell type
            int cellTypeG = cellG.getCellType();

            // getting value from first cell
            key = cellD.getStringCellValue();


            // fetching value to the Double, to be able to compare data
            if (Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cellTypeG) {
                value = new Double(cellG.getNumericCellValue()).intValue();
                 if (value != null) {
                    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                        map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
                    } else {
                        map.put(key, 1);
                    }

                } 
            }
        }

        // cycle which is filling the map
        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: I know that reading the documentation is very passé these days, but what happens [if you give it a try?](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) Only there's [pretty clear and easy to follow documentation on iterating over rows and cells, including with blank/empty handling](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator).....

Answer (score 0):

> Can you help me how to handle cells with null value?

Simply check if a cell is null/black using `StringUtils.isEmpty()`.

For Example, `StringUtils.isEmpty(cellD.getStringCellValue())`. This will return `true` if the cell is empty or null.